# Installing Publify on an existing Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs, publify

I am looking to install Publify on an existing rails application.  I want to have it use the same database as the rest of my rails application.  If anyone could point me to a good guide on how to do so, or has done it themselves, I would appreciate the help.